# OpenAI gym render OSError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet, openai-gym, q-learning

I am trying to learn Q-Learning by using OpenAI's gym module. But when I try to render my environment, I get the following error,

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c269c1129a2f> in <module>
     12     action = 2
     13     new_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
---> 14     plt.imshow(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
     15     disp
     16 

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\gym\core.py in render(self, mode, **kwargs)
    228 
    229     def render(self, mode='human', **kwargs):
--> 230         return self.env.render(mode, **kwargs)
    231 
    232     def close(self):

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\classic_control\mountain_car.py in render(self, mode)
    116         self.cartrans.set_rotation(math.cos(3 * pos))
    117 
--> 118         return self.viewer.render(return_rgb_array = mode=='rgb_array')
    119 
    120     def get_keys_to_action(self):

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\classic_control\rendering.py in render(self, return_rgb_array)
    112             arr = arr.reshape(buffer.height, buffer.width, 4)
    113             arr = arr[::-1,:,0:3]
--> 114         self.window.flip()
    115         self.onetime_geoms = []
    116         return arr if return_rgb_array else self.isopen

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py in flip(self)
    319     def flip(self):
    320         self.draw_mouse_cursor()
--> 321         self.context.flip()
    322 
    323     def set_location(self, x, y):

C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\win32.py in flip(self)
    224 
    225     def flip(self):
--> 226         _gdi32.SwapBuffers(self.canvas.hdc)
    227 
    228     def get_vsync(self):

OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x000000000000001C
```

I get the same error when I run my code from the command prompt

Also, here is my code,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gym
from IPython import display
%matplotlib inline

env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0")
env.reset()

done = False

while not done:
    action = 2
    new_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
    plt.imshow(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
    display.display(plt.gcf())
    display.clear_output(wait=True)

env.close()
```

I was not able to find this error on the internet with gym, so I am not able to solve it. 
I even tried the cartpole environment but ended with the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to dynamically using `ipython-display`.
Change your code to:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gym
#from IPython import display
#%matplotlib inline

env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0")
env.reset()

done = False

while not done:
    action = 2
    new_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
    #plt.imshow(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
    env.render(mode='rgb_array')
    #display.display(plt.gcf())
    #display.clear_output(wait=True)

env.close()
```

This OSError can occur for many reasons, therefore it is difficult to reproduce and debug without verifying everything. But from this error of yours:

```
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\win32.py in flip(self)
    224 
    225     def flip(self):
--> 226         _gdi32.SwapBuffers(self.canvas.hdc)
    227 
    228     def get_vsync(self):
```

Since GDI and the ICD share function names like SwapBuffers, a 
wglSwapBuffers is needed to avoid ambiguity when loading the proc 
dynamically your one display might `lock` another one. *I am not sure* but this seems more likely than any other reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still get the same memory accession error from _gdi32. It occurs with the `env.render()`

Comment: Could you just install `pyglet` again from scratch and run any code from [here](https://medium.com/@yvanscher/opengl-and-pyglet-basics-1bd9f1721cc6)

Comment: Sorry that I took so long to reply to this, but I have been trying everything regarding pyglet errors, including but not limited to, running chkdsk, sfc scans, and reinstalling python and pyglet. None of them seems to be resolving my issue

Comment: Could you edit your questions with all the versions for `matplotlib, gym, pyglet `versions you are using, it will be easier for me to reproduce the error and also for everyone who sees it too...